# Retrieving data from AD with SAML

Tags: active-directory, ldap, saml

We have been assigned a task, where we should integrate data from client's Active Directory on weekly basis. Currently we have working Single Sign On implemented with SAML with them. What would be the best approach to handle this situation? I'm still fairly new with SAML, so is it possible to access client's AD with SAML or should it be done with e.g LDAP instead?
All answers are much appreciated

- Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAML is just an XML vocabulary. It has no functionality such as being able to connect to AD and search for users. That's what the Identity Provider (IdP) does. The IdP connects to AD, usually via LDAP, queries the attributes for a user and converts them to SAML format. It then sends the SAML, containing the attributes to the Service Provider (SP).

The point of SAML is the SP doesn't need integration, it just accepts SAML using SSO. So when a user logs in to the SP, the SP redirects them to the IdP, which authenticates them and redirects them back to the SP with their SAML attrobutes.

If you need to export all users from AD on a weekly basis you can just use LDAP and you don't need SSO.

Comment: Agreed. The IDP does authentication not provisioning.

Comment: can you mark it as the answer if it's suitable, thanks?